# Spectral sequence for a deformation of the differential

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $(C, d)$ is a cochain complex over $R$. Let take a deformation of the differential $d+\delta$, where we assume that $\delta^2=0$ and $d\delta+\delta d=0$, hence $(d+\delta)^2=0$.

Is there a way to compute cohomology of $d+\delta$ as deformations of cohomology of $d$? Perhaps some sort of spectral sequence, where first sheet can be computed in terms of $H(C,d)$?

I tried to consider bicomplex $C^{i,j} = C^{i+j}$, but such spectral sequence converges to cohomology of $\oplus_k C^k$, which is not satisfactory.

Comment: The way to compute the cohomology of $d+\delta$ in terms of those of $d$ - in this generality - should also work in the special case of $d=0$, where we have no information from $d$, but want full information on the cohomology of $\delta$... The setting is to general. Maybe the special setting where such a to-be-result should be applied may lead to some answer.

Comment: A general answer could be $H(d+\delta)=(H(d), \delta)$ that is $\delta$ induces map on cohomology of $d$ and cohomology wrt this map is the answer. This works in your special case, but I doubt that my claim above is correct in general.

Comment: In general, the answer is no. If, however, $C$ has some filtration compatible with $d$ and for which $\delta$ lowers the filtration degree, then you have a filtration on $C$ such that $\mathrm{gr}(C) = (C,d)$ whose spectral sequence converges to $H(C,d+\delta)$. This is more or less the setting to do pertubative homological algebra. Another obvious situation is the one where $(C,\delta+d)$ comes in fact from a double complex structure on $C$, so that $C$ is bigraded and $d$ and $\delta$ have bidegrees $(-1,0)$ and $(0,-1)$.

Comment: @Pedro thanks for your comment, it's helpful. Perturbative homological algebra in the form I know it uses more structure: strong deformation retracts between complexes, and works for homotopy equivalences. Do you know papers where it is done for quasi-isomorphisms?